# Starting monetdb for remote connections

Tags: database, monetdb

I am trying to open monetdb server for remote connections. I understand that by default server only allows connections from localhost. By setting mapi_open=true, mserver5 allows remote connections. The server is started using the daemon monetdbd. Setting monetdbd set mapi_open=true, doesnt work/pass property to mserver5.
In merovingian.log I can see after starting server ( via monetdbd start /path/to/dbfarm) that mserver5 entry with mapi_open=false. 
How to pass mapi_open=true to mserver5?

I tried creating .monetdbd.conf in mydbfram, restarted the daemon, but it didnt help.
The default port (50000) is open. And I am trying to connect via mclient.
Any suggestions/pointers? Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards

p.s server is running on CentOS version 7

Answer (score 3):

Which MonetDB version is this? There has been a change in the development version. To open the database port to allow external connections, you need to change a configuration flag in a *stopped* `monetdbd`:

```
monetdbd set listenaddr=0.0.0.0 <dbfarm>
```

Where `<dbfarm>` is the path to your database.

Comment: Thanks for reply Hannes.
<pre>    
Database: MonetDB v11.21.11 (Jul2015-SP1)
</pre>    
netstat shows that its listening on 0.0.0.0:50000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27252/monetdbd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*                           27252/monetdbd

Comment: So it should be open to remote connections already. If it is still not working, check your firewall settings.